# Unable to renaming a field name using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem. I have a label which displays a name. When I double click on it it becomes a text box and I can rename this text from here and on the onblur event it updates the name in the database.

the problem arises when I give "<" and ">" brackets before and after the string.

For Example:

If I give value like this:

- `>name` or `name<` it works fine
- `>name<` it also works fine

problem arises when I gave

- `<name>` it automatically creates tag like that `<name>1</name>` and I am not able to rename it.
- when I gave `<name` or `name>` it saves in database but its not coming from the database.I m not able to rename it.

Anybody can give any idea why its happening??
thanx in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When displaying the name you need to escape the HTML so the angle brackets display.

You may be processing the input value on the server side to strip out non-alphanumeric characters. Which nobody has in their name, so this seems reasonable.

In any case, I'd check the path of the property value, make sure it's being escaped/unescaped when necessary, and that nothing removes HTML-like or non-alpha characters from the value.